# Proving "by hand" Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch for $\mathcal{O}_E(1)\to \mathbb{P}E\to X$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\to  X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle of rank $r+1$ over a compact Kahler manifold. Let $\mathbb{P}E\to X$ be the associate projective bundle and $\mathcal{O}_E(1)\to \mathbb{P}E$ the tautological bundle.  I would like to prove by hand the GRR formula
$$\pi_*(ch(\mathcal{O}_E(1))td(\pi))=ch(\pi_!\mathcal{O}_E(1))=ch(E)$$
where $td(\pi$) is the relative Todd class of the fibration. I am trying to compute the l.h.s: Let us first denote by
$$y=c_1(\mathcal{O}_E(1))=ch(\mathcal{O}_E(1))$$
the first Chern class of $\mathcal{O}_E(1)$. On the other hand we have
$$td(\pi)=td(\pi^*E(1)).$$
Denoting by $x_i$ the Chern roots of $E$ we get
$$ch(\mathcal{O}_E)td(\pi^*E(1))=e^y\prod_i\frac{x_i+y}{1-e^{-(x_i+y)}}.$$
So the l.h.s is the integration along the fiber
$$\pi_*(ch(\mathcal{O}_E(1))td(\pi))=\int_{\mathbb{P}E_x}e^y\prod_i\frac{x_i+y}{1-e^{-(x_i+y)}}$$
where only the $r$-power of $y$ contribute with $\int y^r=1$. We are left to extract the $r$-th coefficient in $y$ of the power series above.

I got stuck here, is there a way to compute that series? maybe using some residue  calculus?

Comment: There is a beautiful "by hand" proof of Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch for projective spaces due to Hirzebruch, who proves it by a very clever change-of-variables in a residue integral in the complex projective plane.

Comment: As Jason wrote this is usually done using residues, see e.g. the book by Hirzebruch-Berger-Jung or page 5 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05641.pdf

Comment: The residue computations only give the degree $0$ part of the GRR formula in the case of projective bundles (because it depends only on the fibre).